# Different Widgets on theme change flutter dart

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, widget, state

I wanted to implement multiple themes in my flutter app with certain colors. Now I want the user to be able, to switch between dark- and light mode but the widgets are different when dark mode is applied... Look at the designs below

[image: Dark mode, red design]
[image: Light mode red design]

As you can see the widgets are completely different... If you know how to do it, please leave me an answer, thanks!

Comment: The color of widgets are different bashed on theme, you can check more [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes)

Answer (score 2):

to do so, you have to implement a MultiProvider for changing themes, a sharedpreferences plugin for saving and restoring booleans. and to change a certain color you use a boolean. Example :

**mytheme.dart**

```
const MaterialColor myColor = MaterialColor(0xFF134E57, <int, Color>{
  50: Color(0xFFE6ECED),
  100: Color(0xFFBFD0D3),
  200: Color(0xFF95B1B5),
  300: Color(0xFF6B9297),
  400: Color(0xFF4B7A81),
  500: Color(0xFF2B636B), //warna tombol add
  600: Color(0xFF265B63),
  700: Color(0xFF205158),
  800: Color(0xFF1A474E),
  900: Color(0xFF10353C),
});

ThemeData light = ThemeData(
  fontFamily: 'NunitoRE',
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  primarySwatch: myColor,
  textTheme: const TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff010101))),
  appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Color(0xfffafafa)),
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF134E57),
    titleSpacing: 0,
    elevation: 0,
    centerTitle: false,
    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xfffafafa), fontSize: 18, fontFamily: "NunitoBL", shadows: shaDow),
  ),
);

ThemeData dark = ThemeData(
  fontFamily: 'NunitoRE',
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  hintColor: const Color(0xb3ffffff),
  focusColor: const Color(0xb3ffffff),
  textTheme: const TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Color(0xfffafafa))),
  appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
    elevation: 0,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Color(0xfffafafa)),
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF222222),
    titleSpacing: 0,
    centerTitle: false,
    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xfffafafa), fontSize: 18, fontFamily: "NunitoBL", shadows: shaDow),
  ),

);
```

this is Provider of theme
**my_prov.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MyProv extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String mytheme = "mytheme";
  SharedPreferences _prefs;

  bool _isDark;

  bool get isDark => _isDark;

  MyProv() {
    _isDark = false;
    _loadFromPrefs();
  }

  toggleTheme() {
    _isDark = !_isDark;
    _saveToPrefs();
    notifyListeners();
  }



  _initPrefs() async {
    if (_prefs == null) {
      return _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    }
  }

  _loadFromPrefs() async {
    await _initPrefs();
    _isDark = _prefs.getBool(mytheme) ?? false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  _saveToPrefs() async {
    await _initPrefs();
    _prefs.setBool(mytheme, _isDark);
  }
}
```

**main.dart**
we return as Multiprovider

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'home.dart';
import 'package:my_app_name/my_prov.dart';
import 'package:my_app_name/mytheme.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProv>(create: (_) => MyProv()),
        ],
        child: Consumer<MyProv>(
          builder: (context, MyProv notifier, child) {
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: notifier.isGel ? dark : light,
              home: const Home(),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:my_app_name/my_prov.dart';
import 'package:my_app_name/mytheme.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // all colors will follow my_theme.dart theme colors.
    // but if you want to make a different color, simply add a boolean isDark in front of it, then fill it with the color you want
    return Consumer<MyProv>(
      builder: (context, notifier, child) => Scaffold(
        drawer: const Drawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).focusColor, //
          title: Text('My App'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                notifier.toggleTheme();
              },
              icon: notifier.isDark ? Icon(Icons.brightness_3) : Icon(Icons.light_mode),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: notifier.isDark ? Color(0xFF085C75) : Color(0xFF427508),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this solution can solve your problem

Comment: Great this helps me with dark and white mode and the themes but I'm not sure, whether it also applies to the widgets... can I, similarly to the AppBarTheme make a theme for lets say a container that is different when using dark/white mode?

Comment: and can you apply the same logic of the dark and white mode to switching between multiple colorways so maybe a blue one, red one and so on?